# Where exactly Firebase custom authentication can be used and what are main uses?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Mainly token are used for authentication but firebase provides different
Sign-in providers like email and password, Facebook, Google, GitHub and Anonymous for authentication. Then what are this tokens used for?

Can anybody guide me to a use case where this `custom tokens` are useful?

Here's where I got to know about this Custom tokens:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuqEOjBMQWE&t=93s

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

Answer (score 1):

Custom tokens are used when you want to [use a Custom Auth System](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth):

> You can integrate Firebase Authentication with a custom authentication
>   system by modifying your authentication server to produce custom
>   signed tokens when a user successfully signs in. Your app receives
>   this token and uses it to authenticate with Firebase.

For example: Let's say you're developing an app that needs authentication, but you don't want to use the Auth Providers that Firebase supports (Google,Twitter,Facebook,etc). Let's say you want to use Instagram Auth.

Since [Instagram Auth](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/instagram-auth) is not provided by Firebase you can't set your Realtime Database rules to `auth!=null`. You'll probably set it to public, which means that anyone can access your data and this is an obvious security risk(Your database is not safe at all).

So what you can do is create your custom auth system that allows a user to authenticate with Instagram and then give him a Custom Token. The user will then use this token when signing in to your Firebase App, and he will be recognized on Firebase Authentication. Which means that he can now access data that is protected by `auth!=null`. Your database no longer needs to be public.